# load older posts on click (ajax, jquery, laravel)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

how when user clicks 'older posts' button replace first 5 posts with next 5?

PostsController.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::latest('created_at')->paginate(5);

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        // replace first 5 posts with next 5
    }

    return view('index', compact('posts'));
}
```

style.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#older_posts', function(e)) {
    olderPosts();
}

function olderPosts() {
// ..
}
```

what i'm asking it's not code but hint at most basic approach how to do this. there are several examples online, but somehow they're not clear to me. thank you

Comment: Do you have problem in replacing or loading? or finding previous posts in database?

Comment: i have problem in replacing

Comment: in `olderPosts` you will need to append HTML to your existing HTML list of posts

Comment: You would need to also fetch the new posts from your DB, then loop through them and build up an HTML string to then be placed inside the div containing your existing posts